# How to use DRAFT enum in Google Classroom CourseWork.list call

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I've have assigned hundreds of Classroom assignments to 40 different courses using CourseWork.create from a Google Script associated with a Google Sheet.  Within CourseWork.create I use state = "DRAFT" and scheduledTime to a time in the future to publish at a later date.  All working great.

Sometimes I lose track of what I have assigned.  When I use 
Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(course id) I get a list of all published 
but not the draft assignments to be published later.  The documentation suggests that as owner of the course I should be able to list all work.

So I tried using the enum value DRAFT.  I'm not sure of the syntax to use.
I've tried

```
  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(id, courseWorkStates="DRAFT");
  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(id, courseWorkStates=DRAFT);
  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(id, courseWorkStates=Classroom.DRAFT);

  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(course id, "DRAFT");

  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(id, enum("DRAFT"));

  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(id, Classroom.DRAFT);  // this gives a Server error

  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(id, Classroom.Atrribute.DRAFT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in an options Object (with the `courseWorkStates` property set to "DRAFT") as your second argument to the `Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list()` method.

```
var options = {};

options.courseWorkStates = "DRAFT";

Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(id, options);
```